# How to encode structs into Avro record in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-avro

I'm trying to use `to_avro()` function to create Avro records. However, I'm not able to encode multiple columns, as some columns are simply lost after encoding. A simple example to recreate the problem:

```
val schema = StructType(List(
  StructField("entity_type", StringType),
  StructField("entity", StringType)
))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Row("PERSON", "John Doe")
))
val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)

df
  .withColumn("struct", struct(col("entity_type"), col("entity")))
  .select("struct")
  .collect()
  .foreach(println)

// prints [[PERSON, John Doe]]
```

```
df
  .withColumn("struct", struct(col("entity_type"), col("entity")))
  .select(to_avro(col("struct")).as("value"))
  .select(from_avro(col("value"), entitySchema).as("entity"))
  .collect()
  .foreach(println)

// prints [[, PERSON]]
```

My schema looks like this

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Entity",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "entity_type",
    "type" : "string"
  },
  {
    "name" : "entity",
    "type" : "string"
  } ]
}
```

What's interesting, is if I change the column order in the struct, the result would be `[, John Doe]`

I'm using Spark 2.4.5. According to Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/sql-data-sources-avro.html): "to_avro() can be used to turn structs into Avro records. This method is particularly useful when you would like to re-encode multiple columns into a single one when writing data out to Kafka."

Answer (score 0):

It's working after changing field types from  `"string"` to `["string", "null"]`. Not sure if this behavior is intended though.